# how to handle a c# activex event from javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, events, activex

First I'd like to say that I've seen these two questions :
[How to handle an ActiveX event in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/150814/how-to-handle-an-activex-event-in-javascript)
[How can I make an ActiveX control written with C# raise events in JavaScript when clicked?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1455577/how-can-i-make-an-activex-control-written-with-c-sharp-raise-events-in-javascrip)

Now I have this Test control :

```
interface EventsInterface
{
    [DispId(0)]
    void myEvent();
}
[ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None)]
[ComSourceInterfaces(typeof(EventsInterface))]
[Guid("0002EA9A-0BAF-4A9C-8300-7E4D7D371445")]
public partial class Test : UserControl
{
    public delegate void Event();
    public event Event myEvent;
    public Test()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        myEvent();
    }
}
```

Which only has one button.

I'm testing the control in this html page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <object id="Control" classid="CLSID:0002EA9A-0BAF-4A9C-8300-7E4D7D371445"/>
    <script for="Control" event="myEvent()">
        alert("hello");
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

When I click the button in IE 8 it's supposed to `alert("hello")` but instead it throws a NullPointerException that myEvent is null So this means the event handler is not set from javascript.

Why doesn't it work ? and how to make it work ?.

By the way I'm testing the page using the 64bit version of IE on windows 7.

### Edit

I tried signing my assembly but it didn't work, all my googling reveals that my code is right so why isn't it working ? what should I do ?

Comment: You need to declare a delegate and and event which inherit that delegate. Also, you must check before calling the delegate if it's not null to avoid NullReferenceExceptions.. See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/events/

Comment: IE8 + ActiveX? My deepest condolences.

Comment: @Oscar I didn't understand you, could you give me an example ?

Comment: @Andreas I could use IE 11 fortunately but there is no escape from ActiveX, condolences accepted