# Hot to call c++ functions from JavaScript

Tags: javascript, visual-c++, activexobject

I need to call some C++ functions from JavaScript. I followed the steps in [How to create an ActiveX that can be used in a Javascript engine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8731181/how-to-create-an-activex-that-can-be-used-in-a-javascript-engine) and I created an ActiveX object using the ATL C++ techniques in Visual Studio. The problem is that when I go to invoke the JScript I get the error "Automation server can't create object" Code: 800A01AD.

Does anyone know if I'm missing something?

Answer (score 0):

To quote an already [good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5157766/1563422):

> The error "Automation Server Can't Create Object" means that your browser's security settings are too low for the ActiveX control to run. You have to move your page into the trusted sites list and lower the ActiveX settings so it can run.
>
> Personally I would avoid ActiveX like the plague since it is locking you into the IE only world.

Comment: I agree, you are better off searching for some multi-platform alternatives.  ActiveX will only work in IE, after the user accepts a bunch of security warnings.  I would look into WebKit/Qt, it might have what you are looking for (although, I've never used it so I can't be sure).