# Manage Activex .NET Event by Javascript

Tags: c#, javascript, com, activex

I did wrote a simple COM .NET dll (Activex) in order to invoke some method and manage some event too through my Html page by javascript.

Well, after reading many topics about nowdays I'm not able to manage any event by javascript.
I did try many sample, many syntax but not to do for my purpose.

My .NET COM Event are declared as shown here : http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/24089/Create-ActiveX-in-NET-Step-by-Step

Also I've read this post (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/150814/how-to-handle-an-activex-event-in-javascript) but I'm not sure how to extend my ActivexControl in a simple way as suggested.

Comment: I'm afraid, we're not sure how to extend your ActivexControl too, cause didn't even saw it.

Answer (score 0):

The following is a code snippet about my activex:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Windows.Forms;

using System.Threading;

namespace AxControls
{

    [ComVisible(true)]
    [InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsDual)]
    [Guid("61327C9D-EFC5-42B7-BA0D-4A8648797003")]
    public interface IHelloWorld
    {
        string GetText();
    }

    [ComVisible(true)]
    [InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIDispatch)]
    [Guid("61327C9D-EFC5-42B7-BA0D-4A8648797003")]
    public interface IMyEvt
    {
        [DispId(1)]
        void OnMyEvt(int prm);
    }

    [ComImport()]
    [Guid("13AD0E8B-BA3F-4CDE-A7D4-8A311EC1766B")]
    [InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)]
    interface IObjectSafety
    {
        [PreserveSig()]
        int GetInterfaceSafetyOptions(ref Guid riid, out int pdwSupportedOptions, out int pdwEnabledOptions);

        [PreserveSig()]
        int SetInterfaceSafetyOptions(ref Guid riid, int dwOptionSetMask, int dwEnabledOptions);
    }




    [ComVisible(true)]
    [ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None)]
    [Guid("32E6AD29-DD5F-46EA-A4D1-BD2F1E3EE064")]
    [ProgId("AxControls.HelloWorld")]
    [ComSourceInterfaces(typeof(IMyEvt))]
    public class HelloWorld : UserControl, IHelloWorld, IObjectSafety
    {
        [ComVisible(false)]
        public delegate void OnMyEvtDelgate(int prm);

        [DispId(1)]
        public event OnMyEvtDelgate OnMyEvt;

        public HelloWorld()
        {
            this.OnMyEvt += new OnMyEvtDelgate(Dummy);
        }

        void Dummy(int param) { }

        #region IHelloWorld Members

        public string GetText()
        {
            if (this.OnMyEvt != null) OnMyEvt(10);
            return "Hello ActiveX World!";
        }

        #endregion

        #region IObjectSafety Members

        public enum ObjectSafetyOptions
        {
            INTERFACESAFE_FOR_UNTRUSTED_CALLER = 0x00000001,
            INTERFACESAFE_FOR_UNTRUSTED_DATA = 0x00000002,
            INTERFACE_USES_DISPEX = 0x00000004,
            INTERFACE_USES_SECURITY_MANAGER = 0x00000008
        };

        public int GetInterfaceSafetyOptions(ref Guid riid, out int pdwSupportedOptions, out int pdwEnabledOptions)
        {
            ObjectSafetyOptions m_options = ObjectSafetyOptions.INTERFACESAFE_FOR_UNTRUSTED_CALLER | ObjectSafetyOptions.INTERFACESAFE_FOR_UNTRUSTED_DATA;
            pdwSupportedOptions = (int)m_options;
            pdwEnabledOptions = (int)m_options;
            return 0;
        }

        public int SetInterfaceSafetyOptions(ref Guid riid, int dwOptionSetMask, int dwEnabledOptions)
        {
            return 0;
        }

        #endregion

    }

}
```