# How to make a Javascript library?

Tags: javascript, lotus-notes, dom-events, javascript-framework

I want to know how can we write the below code snippet in a **Javascript library**:

```
<SCRIPT FOR="eventlib" EVENT="MyEvent(strTest)">
alert("Uploading files...please wait");
    </SCRIPT>
```

and also below code snippet:

```
 <SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JScript">
        function ctrl::ClickEvent(a,b)
        {
            alert("MyWindowControl_ClickEvent");
        }
      </SCRIPT>
```

I am getting syntax error when I try to write the above snippets in a **Javascript LIBRARY**.

Comment: Stupid question time: Do you just mean in a .js file?

Comment: your code is not even some valid javascript , so unless you are using js in a special context you did not tell us about, your code simply wont work ih a broswer. your script tags are not even valid ...

Comment: I am writing in a lotus notes JavaScript library i.e. .js file. And can you please enlighten me why it is not valid. These statements are used to capture events trig-erred from a C# user control embedded on a web page. These statements work fine when i use them in a webpage but when i try to write them in a .js file, i get a syntax error.

Comment: Check out these links and see what javascript has he used :)         http://support.microsoft.com/kb/316516 and http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/clr/thread/8e5823ca-bbea-4bfe-8826-8717ae16ba77...Think before you call something stupid!!!

Comment: @MujtabaBhat, Phil wasn't calling your code stupid.  He was calling his own question stupid.  It's the same as saying "Forgive me for this stupid question I'm asking."  :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/150814/how-to-handle-an-activex-event-in-javascript

Comment: @PhilH...my apology, I misunderstood your comment!!!

Answer (score 0):

You can't include the script tags when inserting into a Lotus Notes javascript library.  Only functions.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Ken...You mean its not possible to write the above code in a .js file!!!

Comment: @MujtabaBhat, I can't tell if you're telling me or asking me?

Comment: The code above can go into a .js file, but not into the code window of a Lotus Notes script library

Answer (score 0):

Instead of writing the Script block, we can write a Javascript function. From the event handler we can call it.