# ActiveX Event and Javascript Callaback Reigstration

Tags: javascript, c#, activex, activexobject

i've developed a c# Library, registered as COM component. Now i need to import the ActiveX created into a html page with Javascript to use the ActiveX function. All is fine except for Callback, probably i lack in knowledge in Javascript but i'm still not able to use properly Callback. I've searched many example but some are too much deep for my objective and other one can't clear the point, so here the question.

I will explain myself:

Thi is the Event in the ActiveX component

```
public delegate void ButtonEvent(object sender, SignEventArgs e);
public event ButtonEvent ButtonSignOk;
```

This is the snippet of my Javascript

```
try {
    var Lib = new ActiveXObject("AGI.GraphometricLib");
    Lib.Initializer();
    Lib.addEventListener('ButtonSignOk', OnOkHandler, false);
    } catch (ex) {
        alert("Error: " + ex.message);
    }

function OnOkHandler(arg1, arg2){
    alert("Pressed!");
}
```

Obviously the *addEventListener* return an error.

> Error: Object doesn't support property or method 'addEventListener'

How can i properly setup a javascript callback for that event defined in the ActiveX ?

Comment: Look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/379872/3394380) or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/152724/3394380)

Comment: [Here's full working example](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/CSActiveX-c3f43e7d) for VS 2008 on Microsoft Code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ActiveX event handlers in an HTA using Javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41713117/activex-event-handlers-in-an-hta-using-javascript)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Event handlers for ActiveX objects can be written with the following syntax:

```
function Lib::ButtonSignOk(sender, e)  {
    alert("Pressed!");
}
```

However, there is a catch. The nature of Javascript is that

1. function declarations are evaluated before anything else in the file
2. this function declaration is interpreted as adding an event handler to the object referred to by `Lib`, which doesn't exist at the beginning of the file.

The solution is to force the function declaration to be evaluated **after** the variable initialization, e.g.:

```
var Lib = new ActiveXObject("AGI.GraphometricLib");
Lib.Initializer();

(function() {
    function Lib::ButtonSignOk(sender, e) {
        alert('Pressed!');
    }
})();
```

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41888383/111794) for a full writeup, and [here](https://github.com/zspitz/activex-js-helpers) for a library I've written that makes this a little easier.

Comment: Wow. The only way I knew so far was to handle ActiveX events in a HTML script tag. I there some documentation from Microsoft about this method?

Comment: @Jean-XavierBardant There is [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/scripting-articles/ms974564(v=msdn.10)).